# Making a read-only descriptor

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptor, python-descriptors

I've made a basic read-only descriptor:

```
class ReadOnlyDescriptor:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return obj._something
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        raise AttributeError("Cannot set this!")
    def __delete__(self, obj):
        raise AttributeError("Cannot delete this!")


class Object:
     something = ReadOnlyDescriptor()
     def __init__(self, something='abc'):
         self._something=something
```

And it works in a basic example:

```
>>> a=Object()
>>> a.something
'abc'
>>> a.something='asdf'
AttributeError: Cannot update this!
>>> del a.something
AttributeError: Cannot delete this!
```

Is there a way to make the above more generic? For example, instead of having to call `obj._something` in the `__get__` for it to dynamically call it? In other words (other than using decorators), what would be a more general way to do the above?

Comment: How about `@property`?

Comment: @DustyPosa right, I'm more trying to emulate what's going on behind the scenes for it. But yes that would be the effect I'm trying to get.

Comment: `__getattribute__` has try this function?